# Interaction between pdflscape, multicols and \twocolumn

Tags: formatting, two-column, multicol, page

Testing the following source code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \textbf{This code block works as I would expect.}\\
            \\
            \\
            \lipsum
        \end{multicols}

        \twocolumn
        \textbf{This code block doesn't works as I would expect.}\\
        \\
        \\
        \lipsum
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

There are some layout differences:

- How you explain this difference?
- How you can make the output of second code block as the first one?

Comment: Why don't you use multicol inside the landscape too?

Comment: I use it. But I would like to know if it is possible to implement the other way too. Ops, I just corrected the question.

Comment: Hopefully your real document doesn't have consecutive `\\ `

Comment: No :-). It's an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `landscape` environment from the `lscape` package (or its `pdflscape` extension) needs to hook in to LaTeX's page breaking routine to rotate each page. It simply does not support two column mode, which uses a different page breaking logic